# Strange app memory management

Tags: android, memory, memory-management, android-activity, memory-leaks

I am developing an Android application and I think that it is performing pretty uncommon behaviour. When I start the app, move away from it by pressing back button and check the Cached Background Processes section of Android's Application Manager it shows me that my app's cached background process is consuming ~10 MB of RAM. Well, this seems totally normal, but, however, everytime I open it again and close by pressing back button and then check the app's memory consuption it always increases by ~800 kB, it means if I open my app 10 times and check its memory consuption I see it is now consuming 10 MB + 10 * 800 kB = 18 MB. The memory consuption rises with every recreation of app's main activity (it means when I rotate the screen too) until it reaches ~28 MB, then it goes down to ~23 MB and then stays between 23 and 28 MB independently how many times more I open it. Is this normal or should I suspect a memory leak?

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you read this article about how to analyze your apps memory consumption using MAT. http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2011/03/memory-analysis-for-android.html?m=1 This has helped me finding leaks before.

Two of the most common errors I've seen:
1. Long lived context references (e.g. something holding a ref. to your activity)
2. Bitmap processing

Comment: Well, I don't think that there is something holding a reference to my activity because the only thing that I launch from my activity is a fragment and it is destroyed together with my activity so it couldn't hold a reference when it's destoyed. Or could it? I see in logs that both my activity's and my fragment's onDestroy() methods are called. And I'm sure I'm not using any bitmaps.

Comment: And I am not saying that I suspect a memory leak. I am just asking if I should worry about such a behaviour of my app. RAM consuption increases with every recreation of my app's main activity until it reaches some point and then settles there going up and down a couple of MBs.

Comment: I'm almost certain you have a memory leak. Ex. When you rotate your screen it's normal to see the memory increase. But the memory should go down and unused objects should get GC'd. Are you using custom Views as in non stock views? They hold a context object.

Comment: Oh and 9 patches are evil. ;)

Comment: I don't know what exactly you mean by saying "custom Views as in non stock views" but yes, I use a couple of small 9 patch images. But do you mean that unused objects should get GCed immediately after I quit the activity? Maybe they get GCed only when memory use reaches particular point? In my case it would be ~28 MB as I mentioned in my question, because then the memory goes down a little. By the way, my app gets totally cleared from memory after some time if I don't use it. So it could mean that there is no held references.

Comment: By custom views I meant: http://developer.android.com/training/custom-views/index.html. Anyhow when you rotate your screen, the memory consumption goes up because the the app has to calculate how to scale the image("hidden image processing") therefore it will consume more heap space. I've noticed significant performance increase when you can replace 9-patches with drawables. I recently wrote a short example on how to replace images with android custom drawables. http://www.novarata.com/look-ma-no-images/.

Comment: No, I am not using that kind of Views. However, I like your idea about replacing images with drawables. I may try to replace my 9 patches that I use for custom tabs layout with drawables when I have some free time. But first I have to find the memory leak or whatever is causing the strange management of my app memory.

Comment: I have just done analyzing my app's memory management with MAT and DDMS in Eclipse. I was looking at the "Allocated" section in DDMS Heap tab and I saw that when I first open my app it allocates ~4.5 MB of RAM, if I close and reopen my app many times it allocates more memory with every reopening until it reaches ~5.8 MB of RAM and then it stops allocating more memory independently of how many times more I open it. The interesting thing is: when I press "Cause GC", the memory consumption goes down to ~4.5 MB again, so it means the GC is able to free memory but why it doesn't do this itself?...

Comment: Do a quick test where you remove the 9 patch from your layout then check your memory. Let me know the result.

Comment: Did it but the behaviour didn't change. Maybe it's ViewPager, FragmentPagerAdapter or CursorAdapter causing the leak. But I don't keep references to my activity or context inside their classes.

Comment: It could be something different than keeping a ref to a context. I'm not saying that it is always the root cause :) I'd still play around with MAT to see what is using up your memory. The pager adapter caches fragments so that will increase your mem footprint. You might not have a memory leak. It's hard to tell without looking at all of your code.

Comment: But if I only use 2 fragments the cache shouldn't increase with every reopening. Unless it caches destroyed fragments and doesn't reuse them and creates new ones but keeps the old ones in memory until the cache reaches some particular size. That would explain why the heap size shows much lower values than all memory allocated by app. Because the fragments may be cached outside the heap. But no... That's totally ridiculous.

Comment: I've just read something interesting here http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/FragmentPagerAdapter.html and I think this could be the cause of my memory increase. It says: The fragment of each page the user visits will be kept in memory, though its view hierarchy may be destroyed when not visible. This can result in using a significant amount of memory since fragment instances can hold on to an arbitrary amount of state. Then this is absolutely not a leak but a normal behaviour. But still, how many instances of the same page (fragment) this adapter caches?